# Use columns as row and column headers in a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file like this:

```
1   A   10
2   A   20
1   B   30
1   C   40
2   B   50
```

And I want to organize my matrix like this:

```
    1   2

A   10  20  
B   30  50
C   40  0
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

My current solution (using index_0 and index_1 when i want to access something in the matrix):

```
index_0 = list(set([l.split("\t")[0] for l in csv_file]))
index_1 = list(set([l.split("\t")[1] for l in csv_file]))

m = np.zeros((len(index_0),len(index_1)))

for line in csv_file:
    s = line.split("\t")
    m[index_0.index(s[0]), index_1.index(s[1])] = s[2]
```

Something tells me there's a more efficient way to do this using numpy/pandas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pd.pivot_table`

```
In [913]: df.pivot_table(index='col2', columns='col1', 
                         values='col3', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[913]:
col1   1   2
col2
A     10  20
B     30  50
C     40   0
```

Or, using `pd.crosstab`

```
In [921]: pd.crosstab(index=df['col2'], columns=df['col1'], values=df['col3'], 
     ...:             aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
Out[921]:
col1     1     2
col2
A     10.0  20.0
B     30.0  50.0
C     40.0   0.0
```

Or, using `groupby` and `unstack`

```
In [926]: df.groupby(['col2', 'col1']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[926]:
     col3
col1    1   2
col2
A      10  20
B      30  50
C      40   0
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use pandas but you could also have used a `defaultdict`:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

d = """1   A   10
2   A   20
1   B   30
1   C   40
2   B   50""".split("\n")
d = [i.split("   ") for i in d]


# Default value is {1: "0", 2: "0"}
data = defaultdict(lambda: dict(set([(i[0], "0") for i in d])))

# Update values for 1 and 2
for idx, name, val in d:
    data[name][idx] = val  

# (Missing the colum ids, but could be added)
print ["{} {} {}".format(*([k] + v.values())) for k, v in sorted(data.items())]

>>> ['A 10 20', 'B 30 50', 'C 40 0']
```